# Is there a way to inherit a class only if a runtime flag is true in python?

Tags: python

I would like to have an existing class `A` inherit `B` only if a runtime flag is turned on. Is this possible?

Usually for these cases, I either

1. Just have `A` inherit `B` by default, and not use `B` if that flag is False
2. Create another class `A_mod`, that inherits from `A` and `B`, and use this class when that flag is true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a conditional expression when specifying the parent class

```
class A(B if flag else object):
```

Answer (score 3):

This is possible by defining the collection of parent classes at runtime:

```py
flag = True

class B:
    def foo(self):
        print('foo')


if flag:
    inherits = [B]
else:
    inherits = []

# Inherit from a list
class A(*inherits):
    def bar(self):
        print('bar')


a = A()
# Works if and only if flag is True
a.foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:
    def test(self):
        print("Hello from A")

class B:
    def test(self):
        print("Hello from B")
        
def get_A(flag):
    #A=_A
    if not flag:
        return A
    else:
        class A_MOD(A,B):
            def test1(self):
                print("Test 1")
        return A_MOD
    
A=get_A(0)
A().test()
print(A.mro())

inherited_A=get_A(1)
inherited_A().test()
inherited_A().test1()
print(inherited_A.mro())
```

Output:

```
Hello from A
[<class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]
Hello from A
Test 1
[<class '__main__.get_A.<locals>.A_MOD'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>]
```